# Fill gradient colors between points based on dataset as alternative to heatmap

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-applications, three.js

I have a set of data Im pulling from an API and I want to vizualise it in an webapplication with color representation. My initial approach was to create it with an heatmap in vue.js but I want to have the colors to interpolate between the different values. The problem with heatmap in my case is that it wont fill the gaps between each point. Just drawing a circle.

Basically say I have got five points on different x an y locations on a canvas, each points representing a color. I want to interpolate the color between each point and fill the canvas based on the pointcolor.

I have some different ideas doing this;

- three.js where I guess I can achieve this with a shader learping over
  each point
- is it possible to create this with css?
- D3.js?
- or another library

Thanks for your input

Unfortunately I cannot find an image for visualizing exactly but here is an attempt (sorry for the bad quality. Have only got paint on this computer)

Here are every point representated by the white circle. Say this dot contains the color between I want to learp to and from. This example would have seven colors. one on each circle. Then the fill interpolates between each point.
[image]

Comment: Adding of an explanatory picture would be helpful

Comment: thanks. I uploaded one :) hopefully it gets clearer

Comment: Take a look at this shadertoy example https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XtXBDs

Comment: that could do it. porting it to three.js. 

If anybody got other solution Im open for other attempts such as libraries